# How do I install nscurl on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-yosemite

What I tried:

1. Navigating to `usr/bin/` and typing `nscurl -h`.

   I got: `-bash: nscurl: command not found`
2. I then tried: `install nscurl`.

   It just return a bunch of help options for `install`

Comment: Even if `nscurl` was installed in a different path, and you did `cd /that/different/path`, unless you manually added `.` to the `PATH`, you would have needed to type `./nscurl -h`.

Comment: Of course, `/usr/bin` is in the default `PATH` variable, so if installed `nscurl -h` would have worked… but not because you had changed directory to that path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nscurl` is only part of OS X 10.11 El Capitan. It can't be installed on OS X 10.10.

Comment: what a shame... Will wait to El Capitan release, as I don't want to install a beta OS on my Mac

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone tries to copy it over to 10.10 from 10.11 - that won't work either - it relies on changes to the following dependencies in 10.11:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was thinking to do it :)