# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) but server meets criteria

Tags: ios, ssl

```
2015-11-04 15:17:23.236 Testing[2504:80857] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-11-04 15:17:23.237 Testing[2504:80858] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

I did a little testing app with only a web view to show contents of this website:

https://ripemobileapps.com

Server supports SSL, TLS v1.2 and has GeoTrust certificate.

Test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ gives A- grade SSL.

I really don't know what else can I do to open it. If I try to open https://www.google.com it works fine. For sake what else apple demands?

Comment: show me what is in your app's info.plist file for the "`NSAppTransportSecurity`" key.

Comment: It is just default info.plist there is no NSAppTransportSecurity because i didn't want any bypasses.

Comment: From what I read Forward Security is required as well and my server doesn't have it :/ If I add exception will application be accepted in AppStore?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nscurl` command provided to test this. It will test all ATS settings.

```
nscurl --verbose --ats-diagnostics https://ripemobileapps.com
```

Comment: Where should I do this? Terminal says nscurl: command not found

Comment: It is new in OS X 10.11. It should be in `/usr/bin/nscurl`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723623/